# Importing Polymer web components from remote URLs

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I have created a custom Polymer 2.0 based web component which aims to be installed on third-party websites in order to display content managed from my website.

The web component in question depends on 3 other custom web components but also on *iron-ajax*, *iron-dropdown*, *iron-icon*, *iron-icon-svg*, *marked-element* and *paper-icon-button*.

In order to maximize browsers compatibility, the code is transpiled to ES5 by using *polymer-build* with the default *es5-bundled* preset.

Once done, the build folder is deployed on Firebase hosting and I get an URL for including required files on third-party websites:

```
<script>if (!window.customElements) {
        document.write('<!--');
    }</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mydomain.com/libs/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>
    <!--! do not remove -->
    <script src="https://cdn.mydomain.com/libs/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.mydomain.com/components/my-component.html">
```

When I add the previous piece of code in a blank page, I can create a new instance of *my-component* without any problem and all is working as expected.

However, when I include the code above in a web page that already uses Polymer, then I get a lot of errors similar to the following:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on
>   'CustomElementRegistry': this name has already been used with this
>   registry

This is understandable since the import above embeds Polymer but Polymer is already loaded on the page.

I was thinking to exclude Polymer and dependencies such as *iron-ajax*, etc. from my custom web component definition. This way, I could directly use the web component on a page that already embeds Polymer whereas pages that don't have Polymer import Polymer and required dependencies.

Unfortunately, when I have tried, I was not able to generate babel helpers which are usually automatically created by *polymer-build*. Furthermore, even if I succeed to get babel helpers, then this solution will not always work since all dependent code must be transpiled to ES5. This means that third-party webpages that use an ES6 version of Polymer can still not use my custom web component...

The only solution I can though about at this time is to release my custom web component in a private repository and distribute the source to developers that need to include my custom web component in a third party webpage that already embeds Polymer. This way, they can locally import the component definition and include it to their build. Unfortunately, the solution has the major drawback to prevent transparent updates from my side. I need to notify developers about changes or they need to poll for changes :(

Do you have already encountered such a situation with Polymer? what are you advices?

Comment: For polymer 2 you can use bower to define your dependencies and this way after running `bower install` you will have all of them fetched in your local environment (which also ensures you will be using the version that works with your environment). So all of your imports should use local, relative URLs, this way making sure that you don't have two different URLs to the same thing, triggering the error that tells you an element was already defined (which, btw, also happens even if you import polymer twice in your local copy using two equivalent but different URLs)

Comment: .. and if you're not in a project already started with Polymer 2 you might want to also consider checking the Polymer 3 preview, since it switches to ES6 modules from HTML imports and to npm as a package manager instead of bower.. and both these changes kind of affect what you're doing there

Comment: @mishu Thanks for your help. Polymer 3 is not a solution, it seems not stable yet for production. Regarding Polymer 2, I understand why I get the error but I wonder if somebody already had and addressed a similar use case without having to share the original custom element repository to link it locally with an app.

Comment: I think there's little chance to find some way to do this, because, at least from what I understand, it wouldn't be the "polymer way". It's recommended to have all the dependencies locally because this way you can either bundle all together into a larger file (when using HTTP/1.1) or to send them via server push from the service worker (when using HTTP/2). And it's not like you have any kind of "security" from having the component on your own server, it's client side code, so anyone can see it if you provide the URL

Comment: My concern is not about security but upgrades. When third-party apps will rely on my repository, upgrades I made on my custom elements are not automatically propagated. They will have to fetch changes from the repository and rebuild their app to include changes. Finally, that's a way to prevent breaking changes. Thanks.

Comment: @Laurent: I have the same problem and share your worries. Didi you find a solution meanwhile without providing your new tag in a repo? Did Polymer 3 help, which is meanwhile advanced the solution?

Comment: @Mik86 I made the repository public but kept copyright.