# Polymer 2: Combine customs tags from different locations

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'm currently playing around with Polymer 2(*) and have a problem...

I want to provide a service hosted on a dedicated location, that is based on a custom tag, that can be embedded into a random other web-app. I already finished the tag, that encapsulates a small tool and added CORS headers. For testing purposes I wrote a plain JavaScript page that embedded the page. Everything works as expected.

The next testcase is a small Polymer 2 app, that consumes (embeds) the tag, too. Both (the embedding app and the embedded app contain a few paper-*-tags and this is where the problems comes in: The browsers tell me, that they cannot register some tags, because the are already registered. I know, that this problem occurs usually, when different versions of the same tag are imported or if import paths are not consistent throughout the app, but in my case this is not a bug, but a feature. I want to be independent of the technology on which the embedded custom tag is build.

Chrome 71:

```
dom-if.html:305 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': this name has already been used with this registry
at [...]/bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-if.html:305:18
at [...]/bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-if.html:309:3
```

Firefox 64:

```
NotSupportedError: Operation is not supported dom-if.html.js:292
<anonymous>
[...]/bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-if.html.js:292:3
<anonymous>
[...]/bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-if.html.js:1:2
```

`

Any suggestion on how to fix this? I tried bundling in order to flatten the components, but I didn’t succeed in getting rid of the problem.

-- Mik68

(*) Ok, I admit, Polymer 2 is not the latest/current stuff, but I have to stick to it until the whole project shifts gears.

Comment: This usually happens when you import polymer.html from different locations. The component that is stored somewhere else must have the same import path of polymer like the rest of your components.

Comment: Well, no, this is the wrong way round: I want to serve the app wrapped into a custom tag from a different location. This is pretty common and works for plain JS. Only the custom tags don't seem to be isolated enough, that embedding and embedded code cannot consist of the same technology.

Comment: Okay then i´m not getting what your Problem is! Maybe you want to add more details.

Comment: Well, the embedding site is loading the application wrapped into a custom tag from a different (web-)site. Both, the embedding and the embedded code rely internally on the paper-*-tags for its functionally. So the different locations are inevitable.

Comment: Seams to be identical to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258756/importing-polymer-web-components-from-remote-urls). But is there still no solution?